# How to remote desktop (RDP) from Win 7 or XP to Win CE

Tags: windows-ce, remote-desktop

Can I RDP to WinCE from Win7 or WinXP?

I need to be able to remote desktop to WinCE PC from my workstation (Win 7 or Win XP).

Note:
I am able to RDP from WinCE to my Win 7 or XP
I need to do the opposite (RDP from Win 7/XP to WinCE).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not inherently.  Windows CE has an RDP client, meaning you can connect to anotehr PC, but no RDP host.  You might be able to make use of the [Remote Desktop tool known as CERDISP](http://nicolasbesson.blogspot.com/2007/12/enable-remote-display-application.html), which comes with Platform Builder (and IIRC the PowerToys for WinMo).