# Is there a way to remotely reboot a Windows CE device?

Tags: remote, reboot, windows-ce

I know how to restart it locally but it would be very useful to find a way to do a remote reboot on Windows CE. How would i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use **`cerdisp`** application (*`ActiveSync Remote Display`*).

It is a **`remote display tool`** used with **Windows CE**.

[See this blog post for details of cerdisp](http://nicolasbesson.blogspot.in/2007/12/enable-remote-display-application.html).

[A Question on WinCE Remote Display (RDP)](https://superuser.com/questions/405475/how-to-remote-desktop-rdp-from-win-7-or-xp-to-win-ce).

Comment: A bit more details? Is this a standard tool?

Comment: @vonbrand : Yes. It's a standard tool for `remote display` of a WinCE device... You can view and control WinCE desktop on a host machine using this tool.


**Note**: For this to work, the `USB Client/OTG` should be enabled in WinCE image.

Comment: @vonbrand : Details added.